# An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This is the error which Visual Studio gives while running the following code for Windows Phone 8

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)

        {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                var data = rootObject.trueScore;
                score = data;
        }
```

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to catch the exception and look at the .InnerException.

At a guess: your type, or some key member of the type, is non-public